# Multivariable Taylor polynomial problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

**Motivation**

I'm struggling with this limit exercise, cause I've came to a solution where the limit exists but the solution provided to me says that it doesn't. The problem is the following:

*Let $H:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be a scalar field and $P(x,y)= 2x − y + x^2 + 3xy + 2y^2$ be its second degree Taylor polynomial centered at origin.
Determine if the following limit exists: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{H(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}$*

**My solution**

Since we are given the second degree polynomial of $H$, we know that it is at least of class $C²$. Then we rewrite the limit as follows:

$L = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{H(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{H(x,y) - 0}{||(x,y) - (0,0)||} = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{H(x,y) - P(0,0)}{||(x,y) - (0,0)||} = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{H(x,y) - H(0,0)}{||(x,y) - (0,0)||}$

Making the substitution $h\vec v = (x,y)-(0,0)$ with $h \ne 0$ and $\vec v=\frac{\vec x}{||\vec x||} $ then we have:

$L = \lim\limits_{h\mapsto 0}\frac{H(\vec 0 + h\vec v)-H(\vec 0)}{|h|||\vec v||} = \lim\limits_{h\mapsto 0}\frac{H(\vec 0 + h\vec v)-H(\vec 0)}{|h|}$

But this is the derivative of $H$ on $(0,0)$ in the direction of $\vec v$, and hence $H$ is differentiable on $(0,0)$ we know it exists and that is equal to $\nabla H(\vec 0) . \vec v = 0$. Then we conclude that $L$ exists and is equal to 0.

**Provided solution**

But the solution provided to me relies on the fact that $H(x, y)$ is equal to $P_1(x,y) + R_1(x,y)$ where $P_1$ is the first degree Taylor's polynomial and $R(x,y)$ is the remainder then making the substitution we have:

$L = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{H(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{P_1(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} + \frac{R_1(x,y )}{||(x,y)||}$

It use the fact that $\frac{R_1(x,y )}{||(x,y)||}$ goes to 0 and then if we solve this limit$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\mapsto (0,0)}\frac{P_1(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}$ it doesn't exists.

**Finally**

I'm not sure the provided one is the one that is Ok and I am not being able to understand if there is something wrong with my approach is wrong.